# Faster, indexed, heuristic doubly-linked list data structure in Java: implementation

Tags: java, performance, linked-list, deque, heuristic

I have this doubly-linked list data structure that runs all the single-element operations in \$\Theta(\sqrt{n})\$ time (refer to [this post](http://coderodde.github.io/weblog/#eill) and [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/LinkedList)).

(See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266154/indexed-heuristic-doubly-linked-list-data-in-java-benchmark) for benchmarks.)

(See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266155/indexed-heuristic-doubly-linked-list-data-structure-in-java-unit-tests) for unit testing.)

I have plans to submit it to the one of the two projects:

- OpenJDK; to substitute `java.util.LinkedList` with my implementations of the same interface(s),
- Apache Commons Collections4; to complement the lists.

## Critique request

Before I submit it to the two projects, I need to make sure that I am doing mature OpenJDK/Apache Commons code. Tell me about anything that comes to mind: DRY, SOLID, etc.

## Code

Here it goes:

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.AbstractSequentialList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 *
 * @author  Rodion Efremov
 * @see     List
 * @see     ArrayList
 * @see     java.util.LinkedList
 * @since 17
 * @param <E> the type of elements held in this collection
 */

public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{

    /**
     * Number of elements in the list.
     */
    private int size = 0;

    /**
     * Pointer to first node.
     */
    private transient Node<E> first;

    /**
     * Pointer to last node.
     */
    private transient Node<E> last;

    /**
     * Stack of fingers.
     */
    private transient FingerStack<E> fingerStack = new FingerStack<>();

    /**
     * Constructs an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
     * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
     * iterator.
     *
     * @param  c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        this();
        addAll(c);
    }

    /**
     * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
     *
     * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #addLast}.
     *
     * @param e element to be appended to this list
     * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        linkLast(e);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
     * Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
     * subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
     *
     * @param index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
     * @param element element to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        checkPositionIndex(index);

        if (index == size)
            linkLast(element);
        else
            linkBefore(element, node(index), index);
    }

    /**
     * Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
     * this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
     * collection's iterator.  The behavior of this operation is undefined if
     * the specified collection is modified while the operation is in
     * progress.  (Note that this will occur if the specified collection is
     * this list, and it's nonempty.)
     *
     * @param c collection containing elements to be added to this list
     * @return {@code true} if this list changed as a result of the call
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        return addAll(size, c);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this
     * list, starting at the specified position.  Shifts the element
     * currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to
     * the right (increases their indices).  The new elements will appear
     * in the list in the order that they are returned by the
     * specified collection's iterator.
     *
     * @param index index at which to insert the first element
     *              from the specified collection
     * @param c collection containing elements to be added to this list
     * @return {@code true} if this list changed as a result of the call
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        checkPositionIndex(index);
        if (c.isEmpty())
            return false;

        if (size == 0)
            setAll(c);
        else if (index == 0)
            prependAll(c);
        else if (index == size)
            appendAll(c);
        else
            insertAll(c, node(index), index);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified element at the beginning of this list.
     *
     * @param e the element to add
     */
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        linkFirst(e);
    }

    /**
     * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
     *
     * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #add}.
     *
     * @param e the element to add
     */
    public void addLast(E e) {
        linkLast(e);
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of the elements from this list.
     * The list will be empty after this call returns.
     */
    public void clear() {
        fingerStack.clear();
        size = 0;

        // Clearing all of the links between nodes is "unnecessary", but:
        // - helps a generational GC if the discarded nodes inhabit
        //   more than one generation
        // - is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator
        for (Node<E> node = first; node != null;) {
            node.prev = null;
            node.item = null;
            Node<E> next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            node = next;
        }

        first = last = null;
        modCount++;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if this list contains the specified element.
     * More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this list contains
     * at least one element {@code e} such that
     * {@code Objects.equals(o, e)}.
     *
     * @param o element whose presence in this list is to be tested
     * @return {@code true} if this list contains the specified element
     */
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    /**
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> descendingIterator() {
        return new DescendingIterator();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.
     *
     * @return the head of this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     * @since 1.5
     */
    @Override
    public E element() {
        return getFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} only if the input object is a {@link List}, has the
     * same size, and whose iterator returns the elements in the same order as
     * this list.
     *
     * @param o the query object.
     * @return {@code true} only if this list and the input list represent the
     * same element sequence.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return false;

        if (o == this)
            return true;

        if (!o.getClass().equals(o.getClass()))
            return false;

        List<?> otherList = (List<?>) o;

        if (size != otherList.size())
            return false;

        Iterator<?> iterator1 = iterator();
        Iterator<?> iterator2 = otherList.iterator();

        while (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()) {
            Object object1 = iterator1.next();
            Object object2 = iterator2.next();

            if (!java.util.Objects.equals(object1, object2))
                return false;
        }

        boolean iterator1HasMore = iterator1.hasNext();
        boolean iterator2HasMore = iterator2.hasNext();

        if (iterator1HasMore || iterator2HasMore)
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    iterator1HasMore ?
                            "This list has more elements to offer" :
                            "Argument list has more elements to offer");

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
     *
     * @param index index of the element to return
     * @return the element at the specified position in this list
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public E get(int index) {
        checkElementIndex(index);
        return node(index).item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the first element in this list.
     *
     * @return the first element in this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E getFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        if (f == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        return f.item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the last element in this list.
     *
     * @return the last element in this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E getLast() {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        if (l == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return l.item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the smallest index of the input object, or -1, if the object does
     * not appear in this list.
     * 
     * @param o the object whose index to return.
     * @return the index of {@code o}, or -1, if none is present.
     */
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int index = 0;

        if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next, index++) {
                if (x.item == null)
                    return index;
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next, index++) {
                if (o.equals(x.item)) 
                    return index;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the basic iterator over this list supporting only traversal and
     * removal.
     *
     * @return the basic iterator.
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new BasicIterator();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the last appearance of the input object {@code o}.
     * 
     * @param o the object to search for.
     * @return the largest index of {@code o}, or -1 if none is present.
     */
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        int index = size;

        if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev) {
                index--;
                if (x.item == null) 
                    return index;
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev) {
                index--;
                if (o.equals(x.item)) 
                    return index;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list-iterator of the elements in this list (in proper
     * sequence), starting at the specified position in the list.
     * Obeys the general contract of {@code List.listIterator(int)}.<p>
     *
     * The list-iterator is <i>fail-fast</i>: if the list is structurally
     * modified at any time after the Iterator is created, in any way except
     * through the list-iterator's own {@code remove} or {@code add}
     * methods, the list-iterator will throw a
     * {@code ConcurrentModificationException}.  Thus, in the face of
     * concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather
     * than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined
     * time in the future.
     *
     * @param index index of the first element to be returned from the
     *              list-iterator (by a call to {@code next})
     * @return a ListIterator of the elements in this list (in proper
     *         sequence), starting at the specified position in the list
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     * @see List#listIterator(int)
     */
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        return new EnhancedIterator(index);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element as the tail (last element) of this list.
     *
     * @param e the element to add
     * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Queue#offer})
     * @since 1.5
     */
    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        return add(e);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified element at the front of this list.
     *
     * @param e the element to insert
     * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Deque#offerFirst})
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public boolean offerFirst(E e) {
        addFirst(e);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified element at the end of this list.
     *
     * @param e the element to insert
     * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Deque#offerLast})
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public boolean offerLast(E e) {
        addLast(e);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.
     *
     * @return the head of this list, or {@code null} if this list is empty
     * @since 1.5
     */
    @Override
    public E peek() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : f.item;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the first element of this list,
     * or returns {@code null} if this list is empty.
     *
     * @return the first element of this list, or {@code null}
     *         if this list is empty
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public E peekFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : f.item;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the last element of this list,
     * or returns {@code null} if this list is empty.
     *
     * @return the last element of this list, or {@code null}
     *         if this list is empty
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public E peekLast() {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        return (l == null) ? null : l.item;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.
     *
     * @return the head of this list, or {@code null} if this list is empty
     * @since 1.5
     */
    @Override
    public E poll() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : unlinkFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the first element of this list,
     * or returns {@code null} if this list is empty.
     *
     * @return the first element of this list, or {@code null} if
     *     this list is empty
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public E pollFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : unlinkFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the last element of this list,
     * or returns {@code null} if this list is empty.
     *
     * @return the last element of this list, or {@code null} if
     *     this list is empty
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public E pollLast() {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        return (l == null) ? null : unlinkLast();
    }

    /**
     * Pops an element from the stack represented by this list.  In other
     * words, removes and returns the first element of this list.
     *
     * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #removeFirst()}.
     *
     * @return the element at the front of this list (which is the top
     *         of the stack represented by this list)
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public E pop() {
        return removeFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Pushes an element onto the stack represented by this list.  In other
     * words, inserts the element at the front of this list.
     *
     * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #addFirst}.
     *
     * @param e the element to push
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public void push(E e) {
        addFirst(e);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.
     *
     * @return the head of this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     * @since 1.5
     */
    @Override
    public E remove() {
        return removeFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
     * if it is present.  If this list does not contain the element, it is
     * unchanged.  More formally, removes the element with the lowest index
     * {@code i} such that
     * {@code Objects.equals(o, get(i))}
     * (if such an element exists).  Returns {@code true} if this list
     * contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
     * changed as a result of the call).
     *
     * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
     * @return {@code true} if this list contained the specified element
     */
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        int index = 0;

        if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next, index++) {
                if (x.item == null) {
                    removeNodeFromList(x, index);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next, index++) {
                if (o.equals(x.item)) {
                    removeNodeFromList(x, index);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element residing at the given index.
     * The procedure:
     * 1. Find the node N to remove
     * 2. If N is fingered by F, move F left/right
     * 3. unlink(N)
    */
    public E remove(int index) {
        checkElementIndex(index);

        // Loads the removeData!
        loadRemoveData(index);

        // Make sure that no finger is on our way pointing to the node to remove
        if (removedDataFinger.index == index)
            moveFingerOutOfRemovalLocation(removedDataFinger);

        // Once here, the list is not empty and has at least one finger!
        return unlink(removedDataNode, index);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the first element from this list.
     *
     * @return the first element from this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E removeFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        if (f == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return unlinkFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element in this
     * list (when traversing the list from head to tail).  If the list
     * does not contain the element, it is unchanged.
     *
     * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
     * @return {@code true} if the list contained the specified element
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeFirstOccurrence(Object o) {
        return remove(o);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the last element from this list.
     *
     * @return the last element from this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E removeLast() {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        if (l == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return unlinkLast();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the last occurrence of the specified element in this
     * list (when traversing the list from head to tail).  If the list
     * does not contain the element, it is unchanged.
     *
     * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
     * @return {@code true} if the list contained the specified element
     * @since 1.6
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeLastOccurrence(Object o) {
        int index = size - 1;

        if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev, index--) {
                if (x.item == null) {
                    unlink(x, index);

                    if (mustRemoveFinger())
                        removeFinger();

                    shiftIndicesToLeftOnce(index + 1);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev, index--) {
                if (o.equals(x.item)) {
                    unlink(x, index);

                    if (mustRemoveFinger())
                        removeFinger();

                    shiftIndicesToLeftOnce(index + 1);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this list.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this list
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a <em><a href="Spliterator.html#binding">late-binding</a></em>
     * and <em>fail-fast</em> {@link Spliterator} over the elements in this
     * list.
     *
     * <p>The {@code Spliterator} reports {@link Spliterator#SIZED} and
     * {@link Spliterator#ORDERED}.  Overriding implementations should document
     * the reporting of additional characteristic values.
     *
     * @implNote
     * The {@code Spliterator} additionally reports {@link Spliterator#SUBSIZED}
     * and implements {@code trySplit} to permit limited parallelism..
     *
     * @return a {@code Spliterator} over the elements in this list
     * @since 1.8
     */
    @Override
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return new LinkedListSpliterator<E>(this, first, size, 0, modCount);
    }

    @java.io.Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8812077630522402934L;

    // Internal implementation methods begin:

    private void addFinger(Node<E> node, int index) {
        final Finger<E> finger = new Finger<>(node, index);
        fingerStack.push(finger);
    }

    private void addFingersAfterAppendAll(
            Node<E> first,
            int firstIndex,
            int collectionSize) {
        final int numberOfNewFingers =
                getRecommendedNumberOfFingers() - fingerStack.size();

        if (numberOfNewFingers == 0)
            return;

        final int distanceBetweenFingers = collectionSize / numberOfNewFingers;
        final int nodesToSkip = distanceBetweenFingers / 2;
        int index = firstIndex + nodesToSkip;
        Node<E> node = first;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodesToSkip; i++)
            node = node.next;

        addFinger(node, index);

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNewFingers; i++) {
            index += distanceBetweenFingers;

            for  (int j = 0; j < distanceBetweenFingers; j++) {
                node = node.next;
            }

            addFinger(node, index);
        }
    }

    private void addFingersAfterInsertAll(Node<E> headNodeOfInsertedRange,
                                          int indexOfInsertedRangeHead,
                                          int collectionSize) {
        final int numberOfNewFingers =
                getRecommendedNumberOfFingers() - fingerStack.size();

        if (numberOfNewFingers == 0)
            return;

        final int distanceBetweenFingers = collectionSize / numberOfNewFingers;
        final int startOffset = distanceBetweenFingers / 2;

        int index = indexOfInsertedRangeHead + startOffset;
        Node<E> node = headNodeOfInsertedRange;

        for (int i = 0; i < startOffset; i++)
           node = node.next;

        addFinger(node, index);

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNewFingers; i++) {
            index += distanceBetweenFingers;

            for (int j = 0; j < distanceBetweenFingers; j++)
                node = node.next;

            addFinger(node, index);
        }
    }

    private void addFingersAfterPrependAll(Node<E> first, int collectionSize) {
        final int numberOfNewFingers =
                getRecommendedNumberOfFingers() - fingerStack.size();

        if (numberOfNewFingers == 0)
            return;

        final int distance = collectionSize / numberOfNewFingers;
        final int startIndex = distance / 2;
        int index = startIndex;
        Node<E> node = first;

        for (int i = 0; i < startIndex; i++)
            node = node.next;

        addFinger(node, index);

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNewFingers; i++) {
            index += distance;

            for (int j = 0; j < distance; j++)
                node = node.next;

            addFinger(node, index);
        }
    }

    private void addFingersAfterSetAll() {
        final int numberOfNewFingers = getRecommendedNumberOfFingers();

        if (numberOfNewFingers == 0)
            return;

        final int distance = size / numberOfNewFingers;
        final int startIndex = distance / 2;
        int index = startIndex;
        Node<E> node = first;

        for (int i = 0; i < startIndex; i++)
            node = node.next;

        addFinger(node, startIndex);

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNewFingers; i++) {
            index += distance;

            for (int j = 0; j < distance; j++)
                node = node.next;

            addFinger(node, index);
        }
    }

    private void appendAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Node<E> prev = last;
        final Node<E> oldLast = last;

        for (E item : c) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
            newNode.item = item;
            newNode.prev = prev;
            prev.next = newNode;
            prev = newNode;
        }

        last = prev;
        int sz = c.size();
        size += sz;
        modCount++;
        addFingersAfterAppendAll(oldLast.next, size - sz, sz);
    }

    private void checkElementIndex(int index) {
        if (!isElementIndex(index))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(getOutOfBoundsMessage(index));
    }

    public void checkInvariant() {
        for (int i = 0, sz = fingerStack.size(); i < sz; i++) {
            Finger<E> finger = fingerStack.get(i);
            Node<E> node = getNodeRaw(finger.index);

            if (finger.node != node)
                throw new AssertionError(
                        "checkInvariant() failed at finger index (" +
                                finger.index + "), expected node = " +
                                finger.node + ", actual node = " + node);
        }
    }

    private void checkPositionIndex(int index) {
        if (!isPositionIndex(index))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(getOutOfBoundsMessage(index));
    }

    private Finger<E> getClosestFinger(int index) {
        int bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Finger<E> bestFinger = null;

        for (int sz = fingerStack.size(), i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            Finger<E> finger = fingerStack.get(i);
            int distance = Math.abs(finger.index - index);

            if (distance == 0)
                return finger;

            if (bestDistance > distance) {
                bestDistance = distance;
                bestFinger = finger;
            }
        }

        return bestFinger;
    }

    private Node<E> getNodeRaw(int index) {
        Node<E> node = first;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            node = node.next;

        return node;
    }

    private String getOutOfBoundsMessage(int index) {
        return "Index: " + index + ", Size: " + size;
    }

    private int getRecommendedNumberOfFingers() {
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(size / 2.0));
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Computes the recommended number of fingers for {@code size} elements.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static int getRecommendedNumberOfFingers(int size) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(size / 2.0));
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Inserts the input collection right before the node 'succ'.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void insertAll(
            Collection<? extends E> c,
            Node<E> succ,
            int succIndex) {

        final Node<E> pred = succ.prev;
        Node<E> prev = pred;

        for (E item : c) {
            final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
            newNode.item = item;
            newNode.prev = prev;
            prev.next = newNode;
            prev = newNode;
        }

        prev.next = succ;
        succ.prev = prev;

        int sz = c.size();
        modCount++;
        size += sz;

        // Shift all the fingers positions past the 'succ' on the right 'sz'
        // positions to the right:
        shiftIndicesToRight(succIndex, sz);
        //                                   0 1 |10 11 12| 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        // Add fingers:
        addFingersAfterInsertAll(pred.next, succIndex, sz);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Tells if the argument is the index of an existing element.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private boolean isElementIndex(int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index < size;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Tells if the argument is the index of a valid position for an iterator or an
    add operation.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private boolean isPositionIndex(int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index <= size;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Links the input element right before the node 'succ'.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void linkBefore(E e, Node<E> succ, int index) {
        shiftIndicesToRightOnce(index);

        final Node<E> pred = succ.prev;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
        newNode.item = e;
        newNode.next = succ;
        succ.prev = newNode;

        if (pred == null) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            pred.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = pred;
        }

        size++;
        modCount++;

        if (mustAddFinger())
            addFinger(newNode, index);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Prepends the input element to the head of this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void linkFirst(E e) {
        shiftIndicesToRightOnce(0);

        final Node<E> f = first;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
        newNode.item = e;
        newNode.next = f;
        first = newNode;

        if (f == null)
            last = newNode;
        else
            f.prev = newNode;

        size++;
        modCount++;

        if (mustAddFinger())
            addFinger(newNode, 0);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Appends the input element to the tail of this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void linkLast(E e) {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
        newNode.item = e;
        newNode.prev = l;
        last = newNode;

        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;

        size++;
        modCount++;

        if (mustAddFinger())
            addFinger(newNode, size - 1);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Loads the removal operation related data.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void loadRemoveData(int index) {
        Finger<E> finger = getClosestFinger(index);
        Node<E> node = finger.node;

        if (index < finger.index) {
            final int distance = finger.index - index;

            for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
                node = node.prev;
        } else {
            final int distance = index - finger.index;

            for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
                node = node.next;
        }

        removedDataFinger = finger;
        removedDataNode = node;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Returns a finger that does not point to the element to remove. We need this
    in order to make sure that after removal, all the fingers point to valid
    nodes.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void moveFingerOutOfRemovalLocation(Finger<E> finger) {
        if (size == 1) {
            fingerStack.pop();
            return;
        }

        if (finger.node.prev != null) {
            // Move the finger one position to the left:
            finger.node = finger.node.prev;
            finger.index--;
            return;
        }

        if (finger.node.next != null) {
            // Move the finger one position to the right:
            finger.node = finger.node.next;
            finger.index++;
            return;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Removing from an empty list.");
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Returns true only if this list requires more fingers.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private boolean mustAddFinger() {
        // Here, fingerStack.size() == getRecommendedFingerCount(), or,
        // fingerStack.size() == getRecommendedFingerCount() - 1
        return fingerStack.size() != getRecommendedNumberOfFingers();
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Returns true only if this list requires less fingers.
    /***************************************************************************
    ***************************************************************************/
    private boolean mustRemoveFinger() {
        // Here, fingerStack.size() == getRecommendedFingerCount(), or,
        // fingerStack.size() == getRecommendedFingerCount() + 1
        return fingerStack.size() != getRecommendedNumberOfFingers();
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Returns the node at index 'index'. Moves the closest finger to the node.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private Node<E> node(int index) {
        Finger<E> finger = getClosestFinger(index);
        int distance = finger.index - index;

        if (distance > 0)
            finger.rewindLeft(distance);
        else
            finger.rewindRight(-distance);

        return finger.node;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Prepends the input collection to the head of this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void prependAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Iterator<? extends E> iterator = c.iterator();
        final Node<E> oldFirst = first;
        first = new Node<>();
        first.item = iterator.next();

        Node<E> prevNode = first;

        for (int i = 1, sz = c.size(); i < sz; i++) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
            newNode.item = iterator.next();
            newNode.prev = prevNode;
            prevNode.next = newNode;
            prevNode = newNode;
        }

        prevNode.next = oldFirst;
        oldFirst.prev = prevNode;

        int sz = c.size();
        modCount++;
        size += sz;

        // Prior to adding new (possible) fingers, we need to shift all the
        // current fingers 'c.size()' nodes to the larger index values:
        shiftIndicesToRight(0, sz);

        // Now, add the missing fingers:
        addFingersAfterPrependAll(first, sz);
    }

    private void removeFinger() {
        fingerStack.pop();
    }

    private E removeNodeFromList(Node<E> node, int index) {
        loadRemoveData(index);

        if (removedDataFinger.index == index) 
            moveFingerOutOfRemovalLocation(removedDataFinger);

        return unlink(node, index);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Sets the input collection as a list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void setAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Iterator<? extends E> iterator = c.iterator();

        first = new Node<>();
        first.item = iterator.next();

        Node<E> prevNode = first;

        for (int i = 1, sz = c.size(); i < sz; i++) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
            newNode.item = iterator.next();
            prevNode.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = prevNode;
            prevNode = newNode;
        }

        last = prevNode;
        int sz = c.size();
        modCount++;
        size += sz;

        addFingersAfterSetAll();
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Subtracts 'steps' positions from each index at least 'startingIndex'.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void shiftIndicesToLeft(int startingIndex, int steps) {
        for (int i = 0, sz = fingerStack.size; i < sz; i++) {
            Finger<E> finger = fingerStack.get(i);
            if (finger.index >= startingIndex)
                finger.index -= steps; // substract from index
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Shifts all the indices at least 'startingIndex' one position towards smaller
    index values.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void shiftIndicesToLeftOnce(int startingIndex) {
        shiftIndicesToLeft(startingIndex, 1);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    For each finger with the index at least 'startIndex', add 'steps' to the
    index.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void shiftIndicesToRight(int startIndex, int steps) {
        for (int sz = fingerStack.size(), i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            Finger<E> finger = fingerStack.get(i);
            if (finger.index >= startIndex)
                finger.index += steps;
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Shifts all the indices at least 'startingIndex' one position towards larger
    index values.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private void shiftIndicesToRightOnce(int startingIndex) {
        shiftIndicesToRight(startingIndex, 1);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Unlinks the input node and adjusts the fingers.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private E unlink(Node<E> x, int index) {
        final E element = x.item;
        final Node<E> next = x.next;
        final Node<E> prev = x.prev;

        if (prev == null) {
            first = next;
        } else {
            prev.next = next;
            x.prev = null;
        }

        if (next == null) {
            last = prev;
        } else {
            next.prev = prev;
            x.next = null;
        }

        x.item = null;
        size--;
        modCount++;

        if (mustRemoveFinger())
            removeFinger();

        shiftIndicesToLeftOnce(index + 1);
        return element;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Unlinks the head node from this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private E unlinkFirst() {
        shiftIndicesToLeftOnce(1);

        final E element = first.item;
        final Node<E> next = first.next;
        first.item = null;
        first.next = null; // help GC
        first = next;

        if (next == null)
            last = null;
        else
            next.prev = null;

        size--;
        modCount++;

        if (mustRemoveFinger())
            fingerStack.pop();

        return element;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Unlinks the tail node from this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private E unlinkLast() {
        final E element = last.item;
        final Node<E> prev = last.prev;
        last.item = null;
        last.prev = null; // help GC
        last = prev;

        if (prev == null)
            first = null;
        else
            prev.next = null;

        size--;
        modCount++;

        if (mustRemoveFinger())
            fingerStack.pop();

        return element;
    }

    // Caches the removal data:
    private transient Node<E> removedDataNode;
    private transient Finger<E> removedDataFinger;

    /**
     * Reconstitutes this {@code LinkedList} instance from a stream
     * (that is, deserializes it).
     */
    @java.io.Serial
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s) 
            throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Read in any hidden serialization magic
        s.defaultReadObject();

        int size = s.readInt();
        this.size = size;
        this.fingerStack = new FingerStack<>();

        switch (size) {
            case 0:
                return;

            case 1:
                Node<E> newNode = new Node<>();
                newNode.item = (E) s.readObject();
                first = last = newNode;
                addFinger(newNode, 0);
                return;
        }

        Node<E> rightmostNode = new Node<>();
        rightmostNode.item = (E) s.readObject();
        first = rightmostNode;

        int numberOfRequestedFingers = getRecommendedNumberOfFingers(size);
        final int distance = size / numberOfRequestedFingers;
        int startOffset = distance / 2;

        // Read in all elements in the proper order.
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            E item = (E) s.readObject();
            Node<E> node = new Node<>();
            node.item = item;

            if ((i - startOffset) % distance == 0) {
                addFinger(node, i);
            }

            rightmostNode.next = node;
            node.prev = rightmostNode;
            rightmostNode = node;
        }

        last = rightmostNode;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of this {@code LinkedList} instance to a stream
     * (that is, serializes it).
     *
     * @serialData The size of the list (the number of elements it
     *             contains) is emitted (int), followed by all of its
     *             elements (each an Object) in the proper order.
     */
    @java.io.Serial
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
        throws java.io.IOException {
        // Write out any hidden serialization magic
        s.defaultWriteObject();

        // Write out size
        s.writeInt(size);

        // Write out all elements in the proper order.
        for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            s.writeObject(x.item);
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Implements the doubly-linked list node.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> prev;
        Node<E> next;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[Node; item = " + item + "]";
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Implements the list node finger.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static final class Finger<E> {
        Node<E> node;
        int index; // Index at which 'node' is located.

        Finger(Node<E> node, int index) {
            this.node = node;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[Finger; index = " + index + ", item = " + node.item + "]";
        }

        // Moves this finger 'steps' position to the left
        void rewindLeft(int steps) {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
                node = node.prev;
            }

            index -= steps;
        }

        // Moves this finger 'steps' position to the right
        void rewindRight(int steps) {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
                node = node.next;
            }

            index += steps;
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Implements a simple, array-based stack for storing the node fingers.

    @param <E> the list element type
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static final class FingerStack<E> {
        private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 8;

        private Finger<E>[] fingerArray;
        private int size = 0;

        FingerStack() {
            this.fingerArray = new Finger[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        }

        void push(Finger<E> finger) {
            enlargeFingerArrayIfNeeded();
            fingerArray[size++] = finger;
        }

        void pop() {
            fingerArray[--size] = null;
        }

        int size() {
            return size;
        }

        Finger<E> get(int index) {
            return fingerArray[index];
        }

        // Clears this finger stack:
        void clear() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                fingerArray[i].node = null; // help GC
                fingerArray[i] = null;
            }

            size = 0;
        }

        // Makes sure that the next finger fits in this finger stack:
        private void enlargeFingerArrayIfNeeded() {
            if (size == fingerArray.length) {
                final int nextCapacity = 3 * fingerArray.length / 2;
                fingerArray = Arrays.copyOf(fingerArray, nextCapacity);
            }
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    This class implements a basic iterator over this list.

    @param E the element type.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private final class BasicIterator implements Iterator<E> {

        private Node<E> lastReturned;
        private Node<E> next = first;
        private int nextIndex;
        private int expectedModCount = modCount;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextIndex < size;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            checkForComodification();
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            lastReturned = next;
            next = next.next;
            nextIndex++;
            return lastReturned.item;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            checkForComodification();
            if (lastReturned == null) 
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            Node<E> lastNext = lastReturned.next;
            int removalIndex = nextIndex - 1;
            //checkInvariant();
            loadRemoveData(removalIndex);

            if (removedDataFinger.index == removalIndex)
                moveFingerOutOfRemovalLocation(removedDataFinger);

            unlink(lastReturned, removalIndex);

            if (next == lastReturned)
                next = lastNext;
            else
                nextIndex--;

            lastReturned = null;
            expectedModCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            while (modCount == expectedModCount && nextIndex < size) {
                action.accept(next.item);
                lastReturned = next;
                next = next.next;
                nextIndex++;
            }
            checkForComodification();
        }

        private final void checkForComodification() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    Implements the list iterator over this list.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private final class EnhancedIterator implements ListIterator<E> {

        private Node<E> lastReturned;
        private Node<E> next;
        private int nextIndex;
        private int expectedModCount = modCount;

        EnhancedIterator(int index) {
            next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
            nextIndex = index;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextIndex < size;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            checkForComdification();
            if (!hasNext()) 
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            lastReturned = next;
            next = next.next;
            nextIndex++;
            return lastReturned.item;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return nextIndex > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public E previous() {
            checkForComdification();
            if (!hasPrevious())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            lastReturned = next = (next == null) ? last : next.prev;
            nextIndex--;
            return lastReturned.item;
        }

        @Override
        public int nextIndex() {
            return nextIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public int previousIndex() {
            return nextIndex - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            checkForComdification();
            if (lastReturned == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            Node<E> lastNext = lastReturned.next;
            int removalIndex = nextIndex - 1;
            loadRemoveData(removalIndex);

            if (removedDataFinger.index == removalIndex)
                moveFingerOutOfRemovalLocation(removedDataFinger);

            unlink(lastReturned, removalIndex);

            if (next == lastReturned)
                next = lastNext;
            else 
                nextIndex = removalIndex;

            lastReturned = null;
            expectedModCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void set(E e) {
            if (lastReturned == null) 
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            checkForComdification();
            lastReturned.item = e;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(E e) {
            checkForComdification();
            lastReturned = null;
            if (next == null) 
                linkLast(e);
            else
                linkBefore(e, next, nextIndex);
            nextIndex++;
            expectedModCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            while (modCount == expectedModCount && nextIndex < size) {
                action.accept(next.item);
                lastReturned = next;
                next = next.next;
                nextIndex++;
            }
            checkForComdification();
        }

        private final void checkForComdification() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount) 
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    private final class DescendingIterator implements Iterator<E> {

        private final ListIterator<E> iterator = new EnhancedIterator(size());

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasPrevious();
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            return iterator.previous();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    private static final class LinkedListSpliterator<E> 
            implements Spliterator<E> {

        private static final long MINIMUM_BATCH_SIZE = 1 << 10; // 1024 items

        private final LinkedList<E> list;
        private LinkedList.Node<E> node;
        private long lengthOfSpliterator;
        private long numberOfProcessedElements;
        private long offsetOfSpliterator;
        private final int expectedModCount;

        private LinkedListSpliterator(LinkedList<E> list,
                                      Node<E> node,
                                      long lengthOfSpliterator,
                                      long offsetOfSpliterator,
                                      int expectedModCount) {
            this.list = list;
            this.node = node;
            this.lengthOfSpliterator = lengthOfSpliterator;
            this.offsetOfSpliterator = offsetOfSpliterator;
            this.expectedModCount = expectedModCount;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            if (action == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            if (numberOfProcessedElements == lengthOfSpliterator)
                return false;
            numberOfProcessedElements++;
            E item = node.item;
            action.accept(item);
            node = node.next;
            if (list.modCount != expectedModCount) 
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            if (action == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            for (long i = numberOfProcessedElements; 
                 i < lengthOfSpliterator; 
                 i++) {
                E item = node.item;
                action.accept(item);
                node = node.next;
            }
            numberOfProcessedElements = lengthOfSpliterator;
            if (list.modCount != expectedModCount) 
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<E> trySplit() {
            final long sizeLeft = estimateSize();
            if (sizeLeft == 0) 
                return null;

            final long thisSpliteratorNewLength = sizeLeft / 2L;

            if (thisSpliteratorNewLength < MINIMUM_BATCH_SIZE)
                return null;

            final long newSpliteratorLength = 
                    sizeLeft - thisSpliteratorNewLength;

            final long newSpliteratorOffset = this.offsetOfSpliterator;

            this.offsetOfSpliterator += newSpliteratorLength;
            this.lengthOfSpliterator -= newSpliteratorLength;
            Node<E> newSpliteratorNode = this.node;
            this.node = list.node((int) this.offsetOfSpliterator);

            return new LinkedListSpliterator<>(
                    list,
                    newSpliteratorNode,
                    newSpliteratorLength, // length
                    newSpliteratorOffset, // offset
                    expectedModCount);
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return (long)(lengthOfSpliterator - numberOfProcessedElements);
        }

        @Override
        public long getExactSizeIfKnown() {
            return estimateSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            return Spliterator.ORDERED | 
                   Spliterator.SUBSIZED |
                   Spliterator.SIZED;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasCharacteristics(int characteristics) {
            switch (characteristics) {
                case Spliterator.ORDERED:
                case Spliterator.SIZED:
                case Spliterator.SUBSIZED:
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 24 days being asked, just a tiny review, as I actually cannot spend time. It is sad noone found time to do a thorough review on something promising. Probably because of the effort.

Use [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) to compare nullable objects. You do it incidentally and using a qualified `java.util.Objects.equals(...)` (generated code?) where you actually import it too.

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    for (Node<E> x = first, int index = 0; x != null; x = x.next, index++) {
        if (Objects.equals(o, x.item)) 
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The list `equals` should instead of:

```
    boolean iterator1HasMore = iterator1.hasNext();
    boolean iterator2HasMore = iterator2.hasNext();
    if (iterator1HasMore || iterator2HasMore)
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                iterator1HasMore ?
                        "This list has more elements to offer" :
                        "Argument list has more elements to offer");

    return true;
```

do:

```
    return !iterator1.hasNext() && !iterator2.hasNext();
```

or better:

```
    return true;
```

As sensibly you did before the loop:

```
    if (size != otherList.size())
        return false;
```

There is no difference between lists having a different element at some index, or having different lengths.

First one should guarantee the same results, before benchmarking. At least unit tests. Probably you did.

There are microbenchmark libraries that are more reliable ("statistics all lie"). For instance now you are testing your class first. Warmup, garbage collection.

The output could have been nicer.

You inherited pre-generic code of java's beginning and use Object where E would be feasible:

```
    Iterator<?> iterator1 = iterator();
```

That is understandable, even justifiable as internally one does not do E-ish things, but it *is* sad.

To go at some `index` one could go forwards from `first` or backwards from `last`. The latter you do not seem to consider.